# mongodb find documents with the same value for a key but do not know what the value is

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I have the following docs in a collection;

```
{'po_no': '456', 'amount': 0.1}
{'po_no': '455', 'amount': 0.2}
{'po_no': '454', 'amount': 0.3}
{'po_no': '456', 'amount': 0.4}
```

I like to find the documents that are with the same value for 'po_no', but do not know which value is for the key; so the following result will be found;

```
{'po_no': '456', 'amount': 0.1}
{'po_no': '456', 'amount': 0.4}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and then check `amount` [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to be greater than `1`:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$po_no",
            amount: { $push: "$amount" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gt: [ { $size: "$amount" }, 1 ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$amount"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            po_no: "$_id",
            amount: 1
        }
    }
])
```

[MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RqjBKEV0ZoL)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with `po_no` and then filter out the documents where count is less then 1 using [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$po_no",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "amount": { "$push": "$amount" }
  }},
  { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 }}},
  { "$unwind": "$amount" },
  { "$project" : { "count": 0 }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "456",
    "amount": 0.1
  },
  {
    "_id": "456",
    "amount": 0.4
  }
]
```